# How to create workflow to check sensor temperature Node red?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, iot, raspberry-pi2, node-red

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV2ur.jpg)
i am working on a raspberry pi 2 solution ,
where i want to get live temperature of my sensor ,
i am using simple python script  ,the script works fine in terminal(command prompt) and getting temperature and humidity.
I created a Node Red flow and copied that python path , I am getting result as shown in the image below , please help me to get correct temperature in debug mode of that flow. 
from there I need to get those values in bluemix cloud , so please help.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far? Please also take a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I can't understand this.  Please edit your Q to include your code and maybe screenshots from NodeRed. Try to be specific about the problem you need help with.

Comment: Are you using the Watson IoT platform?  Can you export your node flow and post so others can help with troubleshooting?